# Is there a way to separate logging for sinatra app mounted inside rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, sinatra, sidekiq

I'm using sidekiq admin view which is a mounted Sinatra app inside of rails app.  When I hit the the admin panel to look at my background jobs I get a lot of output regarding assets like:

```
    16:36:57 web.1    | Started GET "/sidekiq" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-18 16:36:57 -0700
    16:36:57 web.1    | 
    16:36:57 web.1    | 
    16:36:57 web.1    | Started GET "/sidekiq/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-18 16:36:57 -0700
    16:36:57 web.1    | 
    16:36:57 web.1    | 
    16:36:57 web.1    | Started GET "/sidekiq/javascripts/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-18 16:36:57 -0700
    16:36:57 web.1    | 
    16:36:57 web.1    | 
    16:36:57 web.1    | Started GET "/sidekiq/stylesheets/application.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-18 16:36:57 -0700
    16:36:57 web.1    | 
    16:36:57 web.1    | 
    16:36:57 web.1    | Started GET "/sidekiq/javascripts/dashboard.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-18 16:36:57 -0700
    16:36:57 web.1    | 
    16:36:57 web.1    | 
    16:36:57 web.1    | Started GET "/sidekiq/images/status-sd8051fd480.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-18 16:36:57 -0700
    16:36:59 web.1    | 
    16:36:59 web.1    | 
    16:36:59 web.1    | Started GET "/sidekiq/retries" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-18 16:36:59 -0700
    16:36:59 web.1    | 
    16:36:59 web.1    | 
    16:36:59 web.1    | Started GET "/sidekiq/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-18 16:36:59 -0700
    16:36
```

Is there a way to keep this out my my rails log?  Or put this in a separate log file?

Comment: Did you find anything yet? I am not using unicorn so the answer below does not really help me.

Answer (score 0):

How do you launch the Sinatra application? If you use [unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org) for example, you can do, in the `application.rb`:

```
require 'sinatra'
require ...

class Application < Sinatra::Base
     configure do
     set :logging, true
     end

end
```

And in the `unicorn.rb` file which is used as configuration file you can define the logging directory for this sinatra application like:

```
[...]

# Set log file paths
stderr_path "#{@dir}log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{@dir}log/unicorn.stdout.log"
```

You can do the same with every rack based http server. Note that it's the RACK that keeps logs not 'sinatra' itself :-)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The reason the OP might not have responded here is that the normal procedure to include the sidekiq sinatra app is to mount it in the rails config/routes.rb file, so there is no explicit starting via unicorn or so, but rather rails takes care of that. And by default then the mounted app logs to the standard rails log which gets "polluted". Do you know what to do there?